# Implementing the Graph API?

Tags: node.js

I liked working with the Graph API, for example from Facebook. And I want to implement something similar.

For example:

```
http://graph.backend.com/{user_id OR page_id}/{other_parameter}?access_token=TOKEN&fields=name,id,date
```

The question is how to implement such nodes and what framework is suitable for this graph api.

Comment: Google "apollo server". It has become the standard for implementing Graph API

Comment: @slebetman I understand you, but I want to achieve an identical node design as in the graph api facebook

Comment: Oh. You mean REST API for a graph data structure. I thought you were asking about GraphQL. That's just regular REST API url design - and you are completely free to design whatever url structure you want. Look at Express routing and path parameters